# Adding external jar to maven repository not working

Tags: java, maven, jar

I've installed my jar in my local repo as said in maven docs :

```
mvn install:install-file
  -Dfile=<path-to-file>
  -DgroupId=<dans>
  -DartifactId=<dans-lib>
  -Dversion=<1.0.0>
  -Dpackaging=<jar>
  -DgeneratePom=true
```

I can see in my /home/.m2/repository that the location is created and in the dans/dans-lib/1.0.0 there is my jar file.
Unfortunately when I'm trying to add maven dependency in my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>dans</groupId
     <artifactId>dans-lib</artifactId>
     <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I got error Dependency dans:dans-lib not found. I've got no idea what might be the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First solution is to add local repo to pom.xml something like this

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>local-maven-repo</id>
        <url>file:///${project.basedir}/local-maven-repo</url>
    </repository>
 </repositories>
```

2nd solution woudld be to load jar file

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>dans</groupId
 <artifactId>dans-lib</artifactId>
 <version>1.0.0</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/Name_Your_JAR.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Comment: actually after 10000 reload maven clicks it finally started to work.

Comment: Do not use system scope anymore cause it's deprecated for a long time...

Comment: @mario Sounds like your IDE cached a previous response.  Always do things like this from the command line.